# Spades - Nil to lead

Tags: spades

In the game of Spades, assume you bid Nil and you are the leader of the first trick.

**What is your first lead as a Nil bidder?**
What signals you pass to your partner by doing so?

Answer can be split into two:

1. What Suit to lead?
2. What card in the suit to lead?

Do you lead your shortest suit if have any?
Do you lead your safest suit?
Do you lead your lowest card? second lowest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good answer in the really good Spades book [Master Spades by Steve Fleishman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0971434018), his answer is the following:

Lead the **second-lowest card** in **a safe suit**.  This signals to partner that this suit is safe and that you have one lower card.

Why this is good: when opponents play a low card in this suit, because partner knows you have another low card he don't have to cover and can save his high card for next trick.

This convention also lets you inform your partner if you hold a low singlton, by playing the 2 (or the 3 when the 2 either held by partner or will be played) partners know that you don't have a lower card in that suit, hence you had a singlton.  Now partner will lead that suit on the first oppratonity, so you can discarde a high card in a diffrent suit.